# _.omit doesn't return the expected value when using on monogdb object

Tags: node.js, lodash

```html
 

    profile_img: null,
  app:dev   balance: 0,
  app:dev   donated: 0,
  app:dev   isApplied: false,
  app:dev   isPoster: false,
  app:dev   isLoggedIn: false,
  app:dev   likedPosts: [],
  app:dev   bookmarked: [],
  app:dev   transactions: [],
  app:dev   _id: 60d6f3dff733d110340d9ebf,
  app:dev   name: 'j',
  app:dev   email: 'j@gmail.com',
  app:dev   password: '$2b$10$JIhXrORqrTnDcblobFLSoOaORyZhX2uCFW7uAekF/',
  app:dev  
  app:dev   __v: 0
```

this is the object from mongodb i just need to send a response with all key except password i tried using omit but gets all the keys as return value

Comment: Are you using `mongoose` ?

Comment: yes i'm using mongoose

Answer (score 1):

First use `toObject()` on your mongoose model and then try to omit. Or you can create a method for your model something like `model.safeModel()` which will remove sensitive data from your mongoose model.

For more details on methods:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods

An example that implements `safeModel()` method for your schema to remove sensitive data.
https://github.com/alihussam/nodejs-boilerplate/blob/master/src/models/user.model.js